# Use of Javascript for Validation in each Wizard step of an Wizard Control in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

Hi Can anyone suggest how to implement Javascript for validation in an each wizard steps of Wizard Control of ASP.NET.

Thank in Advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer

[Validate all wizard steps on FinishButtonClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124090/validate-all-wizard-steps-on-finishbuttonclick)

this validates each step using different ValidationGroup on each step